# Getting Promisename.then is not a function while calling the promise

Tags: javascript, promise

Here is a link for my code : https://jsbin.com/pijakayage/edit?js,console

Here is the function that fires the error

```
var  willIGetNewPhone = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    if(isMomHappy){
      var phone = {
                brand: 'Samsung',
                color: 'black'
            };
       resolve(phone);
    }else {
      var reason = new Error('mom is not happy');
            reject(reason);
    }
  });
}
```

I don't really get what is the difference between the first commented function and the second !!! In the second function im just defining a function that returns a promise !  why is it not working?!why am i getting : "willIGetNewPhone.then is not a function" ...

Thank you guys for your help..

Comment: The value of `willGetNewPhone` is a function, not a Promise. If you *call* the function, the return value will be a Promise. So `willGetNewPhone.then()` won't work, but `willGetNewPhone().then()` will.

Answer (score 0):

Because `willIGetNewPhone` is a function

the problem is

```
// call our promise
var askMom = function () {
    willIGetNewPhone
    .then(showOff) // chain it here
    .then(function (fulfilled) {
            console.log(fulfilled);
          // output: 'Hey friend, I have a new black Samsung phone.'
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            // oops, mom don't buy it
            console.log(error.message);
          // output: 'mom is not happy'
        });
};
```

should be

```
// call our promise
var askMom = function () {
    willIGetNewPhone()
    .then(showOff) // chain it here
    .then(function (fulfilled) {
            console.log(fulfilled);
          // output: 'Hey friend, I have a new black Samsung phone.'
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            // oops, mom don't buy it
            console.log(error.message);
          // output: 'mom is not happy'
        });
};
```

`willIGetNewPhone()` instead of `willIGetNewPhone`